# MERGE (UPSERT) - AZURE SQL DWH

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I been working long with on-premises DWH solutions.  Now moving to AZURE DWH.

Right now am up-to doing most of the processing / transformation in Azure Databricks and writing the result set to Azure SQL DWH Staging Tables.

Now I want to MERGE (UPSERT) the Dimensions and Load Fact Tables.

As MERGE is not supported in AZURE SQL DWH, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MERGE is not support with AZURE SQL DWH,  Azure SQL DWH team said they are planning to support this feature. 
Reference: [MERGE statement support](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/13520394-merge-statement-support).

I found this [blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/83c8c480-7b5d-4e5c-8717-15fdb52ed2b4/using-merge-sql-data-warehouse?forum=transactsql), MSFT give an example to  use UPDATE/INSERT statements instead of MERGE.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can someone let me know if MERGE is still unsupported with Azure SQL DWH, aka Azure Synapse?